# Python text search question

Tags: python

I wonder, if you open a text file in Python. And then you'd like to search of words containing a number of letters.

Say you type in 6 different letters (a,b,c,d,e,f) you want to search.
You'd like to find words matching at least 3 letters.
Each letter can only appear once in a word.
And the letter 'a' always has to be containing.

How should the code look like for this specific kind of search?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see...

```
return [x for x in document.split()
        if 'a' in x and sum((1 if y in 'abcdef' else 0 for y in x)) >= 3]
```

`split` with no parameters acts as a "words" function, splitting on any whitespace and removing words that contain no characters. Then you check if the letter 'a' is in the word. If 'a' is in the word, you use a generator expression that goes over every letter in the word. If the letter is inside of the string of available letters, then it returns a 1 which contributes to the sum. Otherwise, it returns 0. Then if the sum is 3 or greater, it keeps it. A generator is used instead of a list comprehension because sum will accept anything iterable and it stops a temporary list from having to be created (less memory overhead).

It doesn't have the best access times because of the use of `in` (which on a string should have an O(n) time), but that generally isn't a very big problem unless the data sets are huge. You can optimize that a bit to pack the string into a set and the constant 'abcdef' can easily be a set. I just didn't want to ruin the nice one liner.

EDIT: Oh, and to improve time on the `if` portion (which is where the inefficiencies are), you could separate it out into a function that iterates over the string once and returns True if the conditions are met. I would have done this, but it ruined my one liner.

EDIT 2: I didn't see the "must have 3 different characters" part. You can't do that in a one liner. You can just take the if portion out into a function.

```
def is_valid(word, chars):
    count = 0
    for x in word:
        if x in chars:
            count += 1
            chars.remove(x)
    return count >= 3 and 'a' not in chars

def parse_document(document):
    return [x for x in document.split() if is_valid(x, set('abcdef'))]
```

This one shouldn't have any performance problems on real world data sets.

Comment: +1 for pedagogical value but I'd be surprised if this could handle a real world dataset with acceptable speed

Comment: It would actually work on a real world data set better than you think. Words are generally not that long and the in statement on 'abcdef' is very quick. If you used something like pypy, it would probably run at similar speeds to a properly optimized C program.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do if I had to write this:

I'd have a function that, given a word, would check whether it satisfies the criteria and would return a boolean flag.

Then I'd have some code that would iterate over all words in the file, present each of them to the function, and print out those for which the function has returned `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = 'fubar cadre obsequious xray'

def find_words(src, required=[], letters=[], min_match=3):
    required = set(required)
    letters = set(letters)

    words = ((word, set(word)) for word in src.split())
    words = (word for word in words if word[1].issuperset(required))
    words = (word for word in words if len(word[1].intersection(letters)) >= min_match)
    words = (word[0] for word in words)
    return words

w = find_words(words, required=['a'], letters=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
print list(w)
```

**EDIT 1:** I too didn't read the requirements closely enough. To ensure a word contains only 1 instance of a valid letter.

```
from collections import Counter

def valid(word, letters, min_match):
    """At least min_match, no more than one of any letter"""
    c = 0
    count = Counter(word)
    for letter in letters:
        char_count = count.get(letter, 0)
        if char_count > 1:
            return False
        elif char_count == 1:
            c += 1
        if c == min_match:
            return True
    return True


def find_words(srcfile, required=[], letters=[], min_match=3):
    required = set(required)
    words = (word for word in srcfile.split())
    words = (word for word in words if set(word).issuperset(required))
    words = (word for word in words if valid(word, letters, min_match))
    return words
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with aix's general plan, but it's perhaps even more general than a 'design pattern,' and I'm not sure how far it gets you, since it boils down to, "figure out a way to check for what you want to find and then check everything you need to check."

Advice about how to find what you want to find:  You've entered into one of the most fundamental areas of algorithm research.  Though LCS (longest common substring) is better covered, you'll have no problems finding good examples for containment either.  The most rigorous discussion of this topic I've seen is on a Google cs wonk's website: http://neil.fraser.name.  He has something called diff-match-patch which is released and optimized in many different languages, including python, which can be downloaded here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

If you'd like to understand more about python and algorithms, magnus hetland has written a great book about python algorithms and his website features some examples within string matching and fuzzy string matching and so on, including the levenshtein distance in a very simple to grasp format.  (google for magnus hetland, I don't remember address).

WIthin the standard library you can look at difflib, which offers many ways to assess similarity of strings.  You are looking for containment which is not the same but it is quite related and you could potentially make a set of candidate words that you could compare, depending on your needs.

Alternatively you could use the new addition to python, Counter, and reconstruct the words you're testing as lists of strings, then make a function that requires counts of 1 or more for each of your tested letters.

Finally, on to the second part of the aix's approach, 'then apply it to everything you want to test,' I'd suggest you look at itertools.  If you have any kind of efficiency constraint, you will want to use generators and a test like the one aix proposes can be most efficiently carried out in python with itertools.ifilter.  You have your function that returns True for the values you want to keep, and the **builtin** function bool.  So you can just do itertools.ifilter(bool,test_iterable), which will return all the values that succeed.

Good luck